# Using (use-package ...) with Emacs 29+

Tags: init-file, package, use-package

I am using Emacs 29.1, which ships with `use-package`, and I want to install and load the MELPA bm package through the init file.

I am using the following `test-init.el` init file:

```lisp
(defun my-packages ()
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
  (package-initialize)
  (require 'use-package)
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t)
  (use-package bm))

(my-packages)
```

and I start Emacs (using the new `--init-directory` switch) with:

```bash
/usr/bin/rm -r /tmp/emadir/*; emacs --init-directory /tmp/emadir -q --load /tmp/test-init.el
```

That is supposed to start Emacs with `test-init.el` and using `/tmp/emadir` as init directory, after emptying it.
Emacs gives the following error:

```lisp
⛔ Error (use-package): Cannot load bm
```

A possible workaround is to move the `(use-package ...)` expression at top level, that is:

```lisp
(defun my-packages ()
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu"   . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
  (package-initialize)
  (require 'use-package)
  (setq use-package-always-ensure t))

(my-packages)
(use-package bm)
```

That gives no errors, however, this is inconvenient for me, as my real init file is huge and I need to use functions to organise it.
What can I do to nest `(use-package ...)` calls inside functions?

Comment: Just adding a `(package-install 'bm)` just above `(use-package bm)` in your first block fixes it. I don't immediately understand why `use-package` does not pick up the `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)`, but for sure there must be some expert here who can provide us with an explanation :)

Comment: @dalanicolai: Yes, I can use  `(unless (package-installed-p 'bm)
    (package-install 'bm))
(require 'bm)`,  do this for every package, and put off `use-package`.

Comment: I am not sure why you'd need to 'initialize' use-package from a function. If you take all those lines out of the my-package function, except for the `(use-package bm)` then it will also work...

Comment: @dalanicolai: 
As I wrote, my init file is gigantic, to make it manageable code is grouped in functions.
So there is a function tasked with loading and configuring stable packages.

Comment: it's not manageable if you can't debug it.

Comment: @antonio Ah okay. Well, I don't understand what you mean with unmanageable; I don't see directly how putting those six lines on top of your init file would make it unmanageable, as all other code can still be grouped in functions. Otherwise, as I said, I don't understand why `use-package` does not pick up the `(setq use-package-always-ensure t)`, and then I hope some expert will be able to explain how to fix it. In any case, good luck!